# Where are the temporary passwords located on mac

Tags: macos, network

When I try to access my Mac Pro Desktop from my MacBook Pro, it doesn't let me connect to Mac Pro anymore , I think I've changed the password without ticking the box: "Remember this password in my keychain"

The problem is, I cannot find the password in order to connect to Mac Pro Desktop.

I have researched this problem on the forum and have looked at my keychains, on which no item exists relating to this problem. I also created a test account on the Mac Pro Desktop  and tried to connect to the  Mac Pro Desktop as a registered user, but that user name and password was also deemed invalid.

Does anyone know where the passwords which are not saved where they are stored on a Mac or  creating a new password or making the Mac Pro Desktop to see the MacBook Pro  as a new Machine?

Comment: When you say "connect" what do you mean?  File Sharing, screen sharing, remote management, remote login, etc?  There's lots of ways to "connect" to a Mac

Comment: Thanks Allan connect via ethernet cable: there is the possibility to create a network in order to share the computer instead of files.

Comment: "Connect via Ethernet cable" is the *medium* and has nothing to do with keychains.  I am more interested in the service you are attempting to connect to.

Comment: ok i ve just used the possibility Network: connect as registered user , i did not use the other possibilities of Screen Sharing and File Sharing...it used to work before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't check the ‘Remember this password in my keychain’ box, that's not to say the password is remembered somewhere else, but rather that the password isn't remembered *at all*.

I'm inclined to believe the problem is elsewhere. This is exemplified by the inability to connect using a completely new account.

Comment: Thanks grgarside  do you have any other  explanation? Could you please share ii with me?

Comment: Thank you Guys for the solutions.After trying all the methods for some reason the passwords start working again even without using the The Sharing Options and the Remote Management Option!